# Assistance on simple authentication system in Java

Tags: java, arrays, split, filereader

I have written a very simple program that reads in a username and password from a text file, where the username and password are separated by a comma. The contents of the text file contains the following
**accounts.txt**
Alex,1234
David,5678

My java application is written as follows

```
public class Authenticate {

public void signIn(String username, String password) throws IOException {

    FileReader fr = new FileReader("location/accounts.txt");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

    while (true) {//read file line by line
        String line = br.readLine();
        if (line == null) {
            break;
        }

        String splitByComma = ",";
        String[] details = line.split(splitByComma);
        String registeredUser = details[0];
        String registeredPass= details[1];

    if(username.equals(registeredUser) && password.equals(registeredPass)){
        System.out.println("signed in successfully!");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("sign in failed");
    }

    }
    br.close();

}
```

}

My App class which called the program:

```
public class App {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Register register = new Register("location/accounts.txt");

    Authenticate auth = new Authenticate(); 

    auth.signIn("David", "5678");
}
```

}

The problem is when I pass in "Alex" "1234" in method for example, the output is
signed in successfully!
sign in failed

And when I pass in "David" "5678" i get
sign in failed
signed in successfully!

I want the application to output "signed in successfully" and "sign in failed" only once depending on the credentials entered.

Many thanks!

Comment: Simply create a string variable with:

String result = "sign in failed"; before your loop. Then change the result if the user was found to your result. after the loop write the result variable over the console output. Additionally you can also do a break when you found the user -> no point to read the rest if you found a match

Comment: i have a better understanding of the problem. Each time it is looping through the file and finding a username and password that doesnt match it calls "sign in failed" until it final finds a username and password it will call "sign in success"n

Comment: If that is what you want simply add break; after the console-output of the success

Comment: still prints both failed and success. This is because the input only matches the second line of the file which is why it prints fail then success.

Comment: see my first comment if you only want to show one status. I'm not entirely clear what you exactly wish to display.

Comment: @Gildraths you are a genius. Thank you, exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

This means you are calling your method twice with different values. Check the calling code (which you haven't provided to us).

Other remarks:

Please don't consider something like this for serious authentication. Passwords should at least be hashed in your file (for example using [BCrypt](http://www.mindrot.org/projects/jBCrypt/)). There are many frameworks which offer industry strength authentication solutions which you should use instead of 'rolling your own'.

You should close resources in one of these ways:

1) in a finally block:

```
BufferedReader br = null;
try {
    br = new BufferedReader(...);
    // do stuff
} 
finally {    
    if (br != null) {
        br.close();
    }
}
```

2) using the Java 8 try-with-resources idiom:

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(...)) {       
    // do stuff
}
```

(the BufferedReader will be automatically closed by the runtime environment)

In your example above you should probably check the input for null values before checking the values with `.equals`.

Comment: this is not for a serious authentication by any means.

Answer (score 0):

First search for the user name. Once found, check the password and exit the loop:

```
public class Authenticate {
    public void signIn(String username, String password) throws IOException {
        try (
            FileReader fr = new FileReader("location/accounts.txt");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        ) {
            boolean success = false;
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] details = line.split(",");
                String registeredUser = details[0];
                if (registeredUser.equals(username)) {
                    String registeredPass = details[1];
                    success = registeredPass.equals(password);
                    break;
                }
            }
            System.out.println(success ? "signed in successfully!" : "sign in failed");
        }
    }
}
```